# Formview.ChangeMode is not working

Tags: asp.net, formview

This is my webpage:

```
<asp:FormView
  ID = "frmView1"
  DefaultMode = "Insert"
  runat = "server"
 >
  <ItemTemplate>
      Item Template
  </ItemTemplate>
  <InsertItemTemplate>
      Insert Item Template
  </InsertItemTemplate>    
</asp:FormView>

<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" Text="Submit" runat="server" />
```

and this is the code-behind:

```
Private Sub btnSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click
    frmView1.ChangeMode(FormViewMode.ReadOnly)
End Sub
```

When I'm clicking the btnSubmit the formview is not showing anything! Is this the right way to change mode in code behind?

Moreover, in code behind instead of ChangeMode if write this:

```
frmView1.DefaultMode = FormViewMode.ReadOnly
```

forview shows the content of InsertItemTemplate. Could someone please explain what's going on here?

Comment: formView1 should show the content of both **InsertItemTemplate** and **ItemTemplate**, right?

Comment: @sarwar026: I didn't understand your question properly, but I expected the formview to show "Insert Item Template" at first as the default mode is Insert (which is happening), and then after clicking btnSubmit the text would change to "Item Template" (which is NOT happening) any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FormView won't show unless you bind, something like this:

```
using(SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql,connection))
{
   DataTable table = new DataTable();
   adapter.Fill(table);
   FormView1.DataSource = table;
   FormView1.DataBind();   
}
```

And just add EmptyDataTemplate tag to show empty message if your datasource don't return any value.

```
 <EmptyDataTemplate>
    There is nothing to see here.
</EmptyDataTemplate>
```

follow this [tutorial](http://www.learn-asp.net/asptutorials/FormView.aspx) and more about this on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228089.aspx)

Comment: I'm sorry, but what do you mean by "bind it"??

Comment: no matter what you are trying to change a mode but In order to use FormView to display any content you have to get some data through datasource. I edited my answer to more clear.

Answer (score 1):

In your code

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" Text="Submit" runat="server" />
```

must change to

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" Text="Submit" runat="server" command="ChangeModeToReadOnly" OnCommand="Button_Command" />
```

Instead of implementing OnClick event implement this

```
Protected Sub Button_Command(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.CommandEventArgs)
   Select Case e.CommandName
     Case "ChangeModeToReadOnly"
       frmView1.ChangeMode(FormViewMode.ReadOnly)
   End Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with adding the following **DataBound** function

```
protected void myFormView_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    frmView1.ChangeMode(FormViewMode.ReadOnly);
}
```

The syntax is in `C#`

Comment: Sorry to kill some time of yours. Did you bind some objects or list with the formView? I guess you need to do it then.

Comment: Interesting, I changed the default mode to ReadOnly but nothing shows up!!! could you pls explain why I need to bind it?